# Расширенная вставка Яндекс Карт на сайт

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Добрый день! Работаю с Яндекс.Картами, появилась необходимость строить маршруты прямо на сайте и с выбором Маршрута, [пример](https://gyazo.com/1474b7ad47994c748c178d7cb17f9ef6) . Как такое же сделать только на своем сайте?

Comment: Вам нужно использовать JavaScript API https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_edit

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. В песочнице JS API Яндекс Карт есть подходящий пример https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_panel_control . Если же вы хотите панель как на Яндекс Картах, то писать её придется самостоятельно, в этом случае поможет такой пример https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control